# Insert values of For Loop into Pandas column

Tags: pandas, python-3.4

I am trying to take the results I get from regex, i.e.

```
['11J']
['4C']
['5,']
[]
['04 ', '05 ', '48T']
```

And store those values in a new column (i.e. Apt) of an existing pandas data frame.

Sample data (Excel file)

```
index  id           apt     address           job description
0     122092476     207     EAST 74 STREET    blah blah 11J blah               
1     122096043     2092    8TH AVENUE        blah 4C blah blah
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_excel('/Users/abc/Desktop/Apartment.xlsx', sheetname=0)
df['Apt'] = 'None'
top5 = df.head()
t5jobs = top5['Job Description']    

d = []

for index, job in enumerate(t5jobs):
    result = re.findall(r'\d\d\D', job) or re.findall(r'\d\D', job) or re.findall(r'PH\D', job)

#print(str(result))
d.append(str(result))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[d]], columns=list('Apt'))
df.append(df2)
```

I am getting this error:

```
AssertionError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

How can I get these values inserted in the Apt column (overwrite None)?

Desired Output:

```
index  id           apt     address           job description         apt 
 0     122092476     207     EAST 74 STREET    blah blah 11J blah      11J         
 1     122096043     2092    8TH AVENUE        blah 4C blah blah        4C
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you edit your question to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: replace: `columns=list('Apt')` --> `columns=['Apt']`

Comment: `columns=list('Apt')` this means three columns: `['A', 'p', 't']`

Comment: How do i overwrite  "None". It still shows up in Apt column?

Comment: @user3062459, can you post your desired DF?

Comment: Please see Question. I included desired output.. at the bottom

Comment: The whole idea is that it extracts 'copy' the apt # from the job description column and 'paste' it in the Apt column (beside it)

Comment: @user3062459, i've updated my answer - is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this (for pandas 0.18.0+):

```
In [11]: df['Apt'] = df['job description'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{1,2}\D)\b', expand=True)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
              id   apt         address     job description  Apt
index
0      122092476   207  EAST 74 STREET  blah blah 11J blah  11J
1      122096043  2092      8TH AVENUE   blah 4C blah blah   4C
```

for pandas versions < 0.18.0:

```
df['Apt'] = df['job description'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{1,2}\D)\b')
```

Comment: df['Apt'] = df['Job Description'].str.extract(r'\b(\d{1,2}\D)\b', expand=True)
TypeError: extract() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand'

Comment: @user3062459, what is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version  .. pandas==0.17.1

Comment: It only fills in the first two values. How do I get it to fill in all the values, as I will run for entire dataset?

Comment: @user3062459, [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)